# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose we have a differentiable real-valued function $f(x)$. The task is to prove, that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x = 0$, and, conversely, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x = 0$ than if the $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists, than it's equal to zero.

I've tried using Lagrange theorem several times, but it didn't help. Could you please suggest a proof, or maybe help me to show that this fact is not true (though it seems to be true)?

Comment: You could use de l'hopital

Comment: To use it shouldn't I get the $0/0$ or $infty/infty$?

Comment: You are right! My fault

Comment: @Shot You can use l’Hôpital also in the form $\text{whatever}/\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not equivalent. Take $f(x)=\sin(x)$, then
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=0$$
but $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \cos(x)$ does not exist.

However if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists then they are equivalent.

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists then it is zero by Lagrange theorem: there is $n<t_n<2n$ such that
$$2\frac{f(2n)}{2n}-\frac{f(n)}{n}=\frac{f(2n)-f(n)}{2n-n}=f'(t_n)$$
By taking the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$, the LHS goes to zero which implies that $f'(t_n)\to 0$. Hence $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ has to be zero.

As regards the other implication, if $f$ is bounded then the result is trivial otherwise we apply Hopital rule .

Comment: Thank you, but I still have 2 remarks:

1) I've stated that $lim f'(x)$ should exist, but in your case it's not.
2) Why could I use l'Hopital?

Comment: If the $lim f(x)$ is not infinity, there are two cases, it could exist and be finite (and this is really trivial), or it could not exist at all, and still f(x) could be unbounded. Or couldn't it? And still no clue why could we use the l'Hopital rule, since there could be no undefinite fraction.

Comment: Is it clear now? if $f(x)$ is bounded then  $|f(x)|/x\leq M/x\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you, very precise answer, but could you please clarify one more thing: you give an interesting form of Lagrange theorem, I know only the following one: $f(b)-f(a) = f'(c) (b-a)$, where $c \in (a,b)$. How did you get your statement, about existance of $t_n >n$?

Comment: +Still not clear what to do in the case of unbounded f(x) if the $lim f(x)$ doesn't exist? Is it still allowed to use l'Hopital rule? I didn't read about that, I thought limits in numerator and denominator should strictly exist??

Comment: As regards the Lagrange theorem, see my edited answer.

Comment: Actually, the hypothesis that f diverges to infinity is not needed to use Hopital. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: Thank you, I'm still not sure about l'Hopital rule, but I'll first read the article, and maybe new questions will arise. But still, very profound answer, thank you again

Comment: The point is, I try to imagine a function, which oscilates a lot, and still unbounded. In the article it is supposed that $lim|f(x)|$ is infinity, but what if it doesn't exist at all (the function is sometimes constant, for example, infinitely many times)?

Comment: You can apply Hopital also in that case. See the note at the end of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof

Comment: @Shot: If you see the proof of L'Hospital's Rule then it is clear that it is applicable in the case when denominator tends to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Also note that it will not work when denominator oscillates. But then the fact that ratio of Derivatives tends to a limit (finite or infinite) prevents the denominator from oscillating.

Comment: Since you are anyway using the powerful L'Hospital's Rule you don't really need to invoke Lagrange. If the limit of $f'(x) $ exists then by L'Hospital's Rule $f(x) /x$ also tends to same limit and this is given as $0$ so $f'(x) \to 0$. The problem is thus an immediate consequence of L'Hospital's Rule. +1 though for trying to avoid L'Hospital's Rule as much as possible (I don't personally prefer it).

Comment: Every day for a something new, thanks a lot, read the proof.